# AJAX TypeError: query is undefined

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, http-post

I'm trying to do a ajax request to my controller in C#, but it never reaches the controller - I get a type Error saying "query is undefined".

Here is my ajax script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Account/GetAllGamesWithRoles',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {},
        success: function (games) {
            debugger;
            Games = games;

            BuildGames(games);
        },
        error: function() {
        }
    });
});
```

Here is my controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetAllGamesWithRoles()
{
    var result = MockGames();

    return new JsonResult{ Data = result, MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue};
}
```

Comment: Show code for your action "GetAllGamesWithRoles". Did you defined that as [HTTPPOST] ?

Comment: Remove  dataType: "JSON", and try. give a breakpoint in  Games = games; and check. Also try this  url: "/Account/GetAllGamesWithRoles",

Comment: Edited with the code I used. Still no luck :-(

Comment: As it is a post call, try passing a dummy string as parameter  to the action and try. It should work

Comment: Makes no difference :-(

Comment: put the debugger; before $.ajax({ }) and check if this ajax line is executed or not ?

Comment: Do not accept answers that do not solve the problem. Add you own answer and accept it to close this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    alert('called before ajax');
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Account/GetAllGamesWithRoles",           
        type: "POST",
        data: {'test':'testcall'},
        success: function (data) {               
            Games = data.Data;
            BuildGames(Games);
        },
        error: function (request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert("Status: " + textStatus + "Error: " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
});


[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetAllGamesWithRoles(string test)
{
    var result = MockGames();

    return Json{ Data = result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet};
}
```

Comment: I found the error. I had referenced a jQuery autocomplete script, which apparently messed up the ajax call! Thanks for your great effort! :-D